# TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I am currently doing a kick command and I am getting this error. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
let kUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
```

Error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using this:

```
message.guild.members.cache.get
```

Answer (score 0):

```
message.guild.members.get(args[0])
```

What's this supposed to be? What exactly are you trying to do?
if you want a simple kick command that kicks the mentioned user just remove that part from your code and it should work.
If you were trying to kick users by simply writing their name, like "!ban TheDann", that's not how it works. And I would not recommend adding such a feature to your bot either. It can happen that you accidentaly kick another user with a similar name. Just tag the user.